# App.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone help me, I am getting this error "App.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
at onInputChange (App.js:69:1)"
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl6Yl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways to go about this.

Since you're not using arrow function you need to bind your handlers

```
constructor() {
  ...code
  this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this)
  this.onButtonSubmit = this.onInputChange.bind(this)
}
```

option 2 - switch your function to arrow function

```js
onInputChange = (event) => {
  ...code
}

onButtonSubmit = () => {
  ...code
}
```

Here's a helpful post to help you understand why

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Answer (score 0):

You can either change `onInputChange` method to use arrow function or you need to bind `this` for the `onInputChange` function.

Using arrow function:

```
onInputChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
};
```

Using bind:

```
<ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit.bind(this)} />
```